# Jquery:How to bind dynamic button with dynamic div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have product catalog. I need to have for every product, a button "show product comments".After button is pressed div with comments must appear.Div must be dynamic too, so I could open a few or more divs at the same time.I need somehow to bind button and div together, maybe they must be in the same class.

```
<input type="button" value="Comments" id="<?php echo $productArray[$key]
["ID"];?>" class="ProductComments"/>


<div id="<?php echo $productArray[$key]["ID"];?>" class="ProductComments" style="display:none"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`data`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attribute

```
<input type="button" value="Comments" data-id="<?php echo $productArray[$key]["ID"];?>" class="ProductComments btn"/>

<div id="<?php echo $productArray[$key]["ID"];?>" class="ProductComments" style="display:none"></div>
```

Script (added `.btn` class to the button):

```
$('.ProductComments.btn').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('#'+id).toggle();
});
```

<kbd>**[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ta4q50Lq/)**</kbd>